# NoMethodError: undefined method `body' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, fine-uploader

I am trying to rename uploaded file and here is my code on image_uploader.rb:

```
def filename
    if !cached? && file.present? 
      new_filename = 'wow.jpg'
      new_path = File.join(File.dirname(file.path), new_filename)
      new_sf = CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.new(new_path)
      cache!(new_sf)
      recreate_versions!
      new_filename
    else 
      super 
    end 
  end
```

While doing

> recreate_versions!

i got into this error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `body' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I'm not sure where's the bit that does the actual renaming. You construct a new file path, but there's no file at that path.

Comment: CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.new file.move_to(new_path) this is not working andshows error : "undefined method `move_to' for #<CarrierWave::Storage::Fog::File:0x00007fe1d020a0a8>" can you guide me better way

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to rename the file that was already uploaded and stored, you can use `move_to` method ([documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/carrierwave/CarrierWave%2FSanitizedFile:move_to)).

Let's assume that you have a `User` model with Carrierwave mounted for an `avatar`. Then, from the rails console, you can call:

```
User.find(1).avatar.path
=> /path/to/avatar/1/image.jpg

User.find(1).avatar.file.move_to("/path/to/avatar/1/new_image_name.jpg")

User.find(1).avatar.path
=> /path/to/avatar/1/new_image_name.jpg
```

No custom code is needed and your problem should be solved.

Comment: i am using carrierwave 0.5 in this moe_to is not available

Comment: It is available but for files stored locally - [source](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/0.5-stable/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb#L172). The problem is that you are using `fog`. In this case, there is no `move_to` method. I think that the only option will be to create new file and remove old one after connecting your file with the model

Comment: Can u guide me for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have any fog to test this and I do not have much experience with that.